# neovim: Keep :terminal active when I switch to other buffers

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer

I use `:terminal` in neovim to run a dev server. But whenever I switch to other opened buffer(s), the terminal kills the process. Is there a way to keep the terminal running in neovim?

Comment: How are you switching? Vim doesnt do that, at least

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I use `<C-\><C-n>` and then `:bp` to switch to previous buffer.

Comment: `<C-\>` sometimes sends a weird signal to programs that causes them to crash. Try `<C-w>:bp`?